# Nginx, rewrite get query

Tags: nginx, query

I would like to rewrite an url from

```
/shop/?category=kitset-kitchens
```

to

```
shop/category/kitset-kitchens
```

What I tried:

```
rewrite ^/shop.*$ /shop/category/$arg_category permanent;
goes to:
shop/category/kitset-kitchens?category=kitset-kitchens
```

if I put "?" like so:

```
rewrite ^/shop.*$ /shop/category/$arg_category? permanent;
goes to:
shop/category/
```

I tried to play with variables, but the result is the same. As soon as 
$args set to '' all other variables are empty, otherwise, it adds get query at the end of the URL. What am I doing wrong?

I would like to not use conditions

Comment: You could try: `location = /shop/ { return 301 /shop/category/$arg_category; }

Comment: works like a charm -> location = /shop/ { if($arg_category) {
   return 301 /shop/category/$arg_category; } #other stuff.... }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that the browser will take into consideration the query parameters after caching the redirect. This means that after browser follow a redirect from `/shop/?category=kitset-kitchens` to `/shop/category/kitset-kitchens` once, it will redirect you to the same page even if the `category` query parameter will have another value. Different browsers can behave differently, so this subject needs some testing.

Back to the question, for clearing `category` query parameter preserving all the others you can use

```
    location = /shop/ {
        if ($args ~ (.*)(^|&)category=[^&]*(\2|$)&?(.*)) {
            # preserve 'category' parameter value
            set $category $arg_category;
            # remove 'category' parameter from query string
            set $args $1$3$4;
            # rewrite URI or do redirection
            rewrite ^ /shop/category/$category break;
        }
        # if you need to pass the request to an upstream, use
        proxy_pass http://upstream$uri$is_args$args;
    }
```

Please note that with this configuration web address in the user's browser won't change from `example.com/shop/?category=kitset-kitchens` to `example.com/shop/category/kitset-kitchens` (we use only internal rewriting here). You can try a redirect (change `break` flag of `rewrite` directive to `permanent`), but as I already said, this configuration needs testing through various browsers because of possible caching issues. You can also try temporary redirection (use `redirect` flag for that).

You said that you would like to not use conditions, but since there are no other directives except `set` and `rewrite` inside the `if` block, it may be considered safe.